# jQuery Validation Plugin not valid if matches

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using the jQuery Validation Plugin and I am running into an issue.

I have a drop down box that can have a couple different errors.

It could have an option for "No Manager Defined", "No Member Defined" or "Select an option above".

How do I make the plugin see these as invalid form submissions?

The one I am trying to work on is for owner.

```
jQuery("#AddFunctionForm").validate({
        rules: {
            owner: "required",
            name: "required", 
            description: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            owner: "Test",
            name: "Function name is required.",
            description: "Description is required."
        },
        highlight: function(label) {
            jQuery(label).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
        },
        success: function(label) {
            label
                .addClass('valid')
                .closest('.control-group').addClass('success');
        }
    });
```

Comment: _How do I make the plugin see these as invalid form submissions_ ?...see what?..if any value is selected in your list or not, or if any particular value is selected from list ?

Comment: "owner" is marked as required.  However when I select "Select an Option Above" which is one of the default optionsreturned through Ajax which has no value assigned and I click Submit.  This option is not marked as invalid and no message is given.  If they select these values and try to submit the form it needs to error out.  @pXL

Comment: That mean,, when anything is selected other then the default, you want to prevent the form submit ?

Comment: @pXL There are three messages the user can 'technically' select that I want to return an error if selected. "Select an Option Above", "No Manager Defined", "No Member Defined".  If any of those three are 'selected' I want to use jQuery Validation to give them an error and have them correct the problem.

Comment: I require help on this issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225962/jquery-form-disable-submit-button-until-required-field-entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use something like this to define a new rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod(
    'newRuleName', function (value, element) {
        return value !== 'UNACCEPTABLE_VALUE';
    }
);
```

Then use it like this:

```
rules: {
    fieldName: 'required newRuleName',
},
messages: {
    fieldName: {
        required: 'Field is required',
        newRuleName: 'You cannot select this value.'
    }
},
```

[**jsfiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/XNVUS/)

Comment: This method works, but it appears my chosen select plugin is interfering with this.  I remove the chzn call to turn the select element into a chosen drop down box and it works just fine.  I add it and it stops working...